# Chance to get one of the two desired result from three picks

Tags: probability

Let's say I have 6 cards, 2 of them is a Joker and the rest are Aces. What are the chance to get at least one of the Joker if I can pick 3 cards after it being shuffled?

What's the formula behind it?

Comment: $$P(j)= 1 - P(\tilde{j})$$

where $P(j)$ means probability of getting at least one joker and $P(\tilde{j})$ is the probability of getting no joker. Now just compute the probability of getting no jokers.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for this kind of problem is using the pmf of hypergeometric distribution. The probability of no Joker inside the 3 cards is

$$ \frac {\displaystyle \binom {2} {0} \binom {4} {3}} {\displaystyle \binom {6} {3}}$$

So the probability having at least one Joker is

$$ 1 - \frac {\displaystyle \binom {2} {0} \binom {4} {3}} {\displaystyle \binom {6} {3}}$$